# How to get the round off value of a decimal in C#

Tags: c#

I want to get the round off value of a decimal number Suppose I am getting 24.86 than i want to get 25 as final value

Comment: Have you considered to search for `Round C#`?

Comment: Why don't do a little search before asking?? [Decimal.Round](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.round.aspx)

Comment: yeah I know about Math.Round but i want to do it by my own logic

Comment: @Ankit: Please edit your question with the logic you need to implement / why you don't need to use `Math.Round()`!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply

```
Math.Round(24.86)
```

This will round you value to 25.

Your own logic will be

```
decimal d = 1.5m;
decimal r = d - Math.Truncate(d);

if (r > 0)
     r = 1 - r;

decimal value = d + r;
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at [`Math.Round(decimal)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s2d3xkk.aspx) and the overload which  [accepts a `MidpointRounding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131274.aspx)  argument.

Comment: Is there any other way?

Comment: What is wrong with this one?

Comment: Nothing wrong. I am trying to do it by my own logic

Comment: @Ankit: For your own logic read my answer.